# Htacces redirect specific slugs

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

i'm trying to configuring .htaccess to force redirect to specific subdomain.

Let's suppose i have a example.com domain with many subdomains, so that finally i have this domains and subdomains:

- example.com
- www.example.com
- demo.example.com
- test.example.com

What i want is that opening the link `example.com/test` or `www.example.com/test`, htaccess should force a redirec to `test.example.com`, while for others domains it shouldn't.

So basically:

- **example.com/test       -> test.example.com**  (redirect)
- **www.example.com/test   -> test.example.com**  (redirect)
- demo.example.com/test  -> demo.example.com/test (no redirect)
- test.example.com/test  -> test.example.com/test (no redirect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this redirect rule in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(example\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^test(/.*)?$ http://test.%1$1 [L,NC,R=301,NE]
```